# Add a product to a specific Store Group?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, admin, multistore

I am trying to save a product programatically. How can i save that product to a particular store group alone. I read in the magento intro, that a storegroup is a collection of products, But i couldn't find any parameter in product model, which restricts a product to a store group.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add products to store groups. You can only assign products to websites

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1,2,3));
```

Or set their visibility to a certain value in a store view.

```
$product->setStoreId(2)->load(15)->setVisibility(1)->save(); //visibility can be from 1 to 4.
```